# Is it possible to identify the datatype of an object at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

It is possible to identify the datatype at runtime using RTTI, but **how do we do it at compile time**, is it even possible ?

Comment: Do you mean `decltype`?

Comment: it's impossible to get real dynamic type in compile time, you can get static type though.

Answer (score 5):

`decltype` gets the underlying type at compile time. The standard defines many utilities, called traits, that perform checks on types.

- Most of the type traits appear in [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)
- Many arithmetic type traits are located in [`<limits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits)

---

E.g. combining these traits with [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) allows compile time branching. A basic example:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T object) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(object), std::string>) {
        std::cout << '"' << object << "\"\n";
    }
    if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<decltype(object)>) {
        std::cout << "unsigned\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<decltype(object)>) {
        std::cout << *object << '\n';
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<foo, decltype(object)>) {
        std::cout << "derived from foo\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't support polymorphism

Comment: @AlanBirtles it won't support *dynamic* polymorphism. This *is* static polymorphism.

Comment: @Caleth yep, but given the question asks about RTTI that would imply dynamic polymorphism (though it's not clear what they're actually trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

C++ supports Template Meta programming. Meta programming means compile time programming where we can work with types rather than values. This is achieved mainly with the trickery of Template specialization

For example, following code can be used to query a type, say, to identify whether a particular type is a pointer or not. All of it happens at compile time

```
template<class T>
struct isPointer{
static bool value = false;
}

template<class T> // Template specialization 
struct isPointer<T*>{
static bool value = true;
}
```